# Is there a way to assign an entire folder to a font family?

Tags: css

I downloaded [this font](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/), which has a lot of font files in the folder downloaded. I've tried

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "Cascadia Code";
 src: url("fonts/Cascadia/static/") format:('truetype');
}
```

but when I try to use it in the site,

```
body {
 font-family: "Cascadia Code";
 font-weight: "light";
}
```

the bold font gets selected instead of the light font, like I want it to. Is there a way to select the font weight automatically or do I have to enter each font file as separate entries?

Comment: CSS is exactly like it sounds -- *Cascading* --  So if you want a different font, even if it's bold / italic of the same *family* --  You will have to specify it. In your CSS if there's multiple fonts --  You could set each as a class to make it easier on yourself .. EG `.cascadia-italic{ ...`  --  `.cascadia-weight{` etc etc

Comment: You have to define all the font variants in `@font-face`